# Youtube API only showing old videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Since yesterday, one of the websites I manage that uses the Youtube API to list videos is only showing videos from ten years before... it should be showing the latest ones. The channel and API key are correct, and I cannot find the source of the problem. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Can you share the channel of the video which is showing this problem?

Comment: Of course: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC95sqZ9GCdR6ReveqiBcUsg

Comment: it seems it's a common problem ocurring to end-users of the YouTube API, as you can check in the answer provided in yor question, it's a Google problem with its API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that it might be related to issue #128673552, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128673552.