# Youtube API 3 get latest videos from a channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use youtube api to fetch the latest video uploaded in a channel and the query is as below

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={KEY}&channelId={CHANNEL-ID}&part=snippet&maxResults=1&order=date&type=video
```

But it is not returning the latest video uploaded in that channel. Adding or removing order attribute doesn't seem to work as it keeps returning the same video.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198893/4092887

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube API only showing old videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198104/youtube-api-only-showing-old-videos)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to do this by fetching playlist items. Get your channel id. It should look like this: `UC######################`. Now you have to replace the 'C' to 'U'. Like this: `UU######################`. You can call the youtube api with this id now.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UU######################&maxResults=5&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Comment: I got following error. How do you increase quota. I have 200k users and watching the live. 
The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e.

Comment: I was using the following URL for a while and it worked fine, suddenly I got an error recently and following your guidance to change UC to UU actually fixed it without any other change - very strange!! https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId=__UCID__&maxResults=__Results__&key=__ApiKey__